# How to update view title

Tags: eclipse-rcp, rcp

I'm trying to update the title of a view (ie : the text displayed in the tab) programmatically.

When i do that :

```
view.setPartName(newTitle);
```

The view name is well updated but the UI is not. So how can i do that ?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: @david & @Duncan Krebs : You are both right! We must call the `setPartname`method inside the `init` method. So, to fix my issue, i used a special object which store the name of my `IViewPart` and I retrieve this one in the `init` method of my `IViewPart`! Thanks a lot for both of you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to make sure you are setting partName in the correct init method and that you make a call to super before setting part name like this. I know this example works pasted from my app.

```
@Override
public void init(IViewSite site) throws PartInitException {
    super.init(site);
    String scannerName = site.getSecondaryId();
    setPartName("MyName");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm updating a view's title without a problem ... when are you invoking the setPartName method?

In my class, which extends `ViewPart`, I'm invoking the `setPartName` method in the `init` method.

Comment: The problem is i call the `setPartName` method outside the `ViewPart`.

Comment: How are you calling the setPartName method?  It's protected.  At least as far as I can tell.  http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/ui/part/ViewPart.html#setPartName(java.lang.String)

Comment: In my `ViewPart` class,I wrote a public method called `changePartName(String newName)` which calls the `setPartName` method. And I use my method `changePartName` elsewhere.

Comment: I dug into the WorkbenchPart code and noticed that, when the content description method is invoked, they fire the `IWorkbenchPartConstants.PROP_CONTENT_DESCRIPTION` event.  Maybe you can do something similar in your changePartName method?

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not work... I tried both `firePropertyChange(IWorkbenchPartConstants.PROP_PART_NAME);` and `firePropertyChange(IWorkbenchPart.PROP_TITLE);`